# Windows 10 keyboard shortcut for Notification Panel?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a Windows 10 keyboard shortcut for Notification Panel?

I have Lenovo ThinkPad for my work computer and I cannot seem to get to the Notification Panel. (maybe it's blocked?)

I have tried Win + A and that doesn't show anything.

I **do** have functions like Win + P.

[image: enter image description here]]

On my personal Microsoft Surface Pro 3, I just swipe from the right side of the screen.

Comment: Win-A works perfectly fine for me. However, you also don’t have the icon next to the clock.

Comment: Paste this into a new browser tab and click go `ms-settings:notifications?activationSource=SMC-IA-4028678` then check you have notifications configured

Comment: `Win+B` takes you to the notification area. Arrow keys move among all the icons including the action centre and press enter on the up arrow to display hidden icons. `Win+A` takes you straight to the action centre.

Answer (score 6):

- Right click on the Taskbar
- Open **Taskbar Settings**
- Scroll down to "**Notification Area**" > Click on "**Turn System icons on or off**"
- Toggle **Action Center** to "**ON**"

After this Win Key + A will also work.And if you have synaptics touchpad driver installed, then you can also open the Action Center by clicking/tapping all 4 fingers(exclude the thumb) on the touchpad. But if you don't have synaptics driver, you can download it from lenovo website.

Tip: Another touchpad shortcut is to swipe three fingers from top to bottom and this will minimize all the open windows.

Comment: Thanks All for the replies.i

I checked @Elmo's directions on the work laptop and "Action Center" and its switch are grayed out. So, it looks like work IT has this functionality disabled... weird?!

Again thanks for your help!

Comment: @gravymatt You could ask your admin to have it enabled or if you have admin rights then follow instructions here: https://www.howtogeek.com/244539/how-to-disable-the-action-center-in-windows-10/